# a slider menu is compromised in space

Tags: css, slideshow

I downloaded a theme from wpexplorer to use for the gallery and right out of the box I see that slider images it falls below post contents. I can adjust the the space thereby pushing the overlapping content down, using height argument. However I notice that the way the slider's navigation arrows and buttons are set up they would not move accordingly. I like to know what is the elegant solution so that everything (the posts bellow and slider's navigation) work around various image sizes like it was intended in the first place. Here is my theme (http://www.manartgallery.com/) and here is the source (http://www.wpexplorer.me/tetris/)
This will be a great help to the gallery. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I can see the problem is that `max-height: 120px` is set in the inline css of `<div id="soliloquy-container-1124" class="soliloquy-container soliloquy-fade">`. Removing that style solves the issue.

Comment: Hi Sunyatasattva. I was thinking and the problem why it's not running out of the box, is that they changed the plugin that run the slider (soliloquy) to a pro version and did not update the theme.

You are right about max-height. This is being introduced from the template files, either from the plugin or theme file...

Comment: Then why don't you just change the theme or plugin? If you really don't know how to do it add this rule to your stylesheet: `.soliloquy-container { max-height: none !important }`. Though the use of `important` is not usually recommended, if it is your best option, go for it.